# Unable to load a do-nothing module with a command line parameter

Tags: module, linux-kernel, kernel, fedora, kernel-module

We have a very simple do-nothing module, as shown:

```
 #include "linux/kernel.h"
 #include "linux/module.h"

 static unsigned int hwmode = 0;    
 module_param(hwmode, uint, 0755); 

 static int __init sig_mc_hw_init(void) 
  {
   printk( " Inside init function, hwmode = %d\n", hwmode);
   return 0;
  }
 static void __exit sig_mc_hw_exit(void) 
  { 
   printk( " Inside exit function\n");
  }
  module_init(sig_mc_hw_init);
  module_exit(sig_mc_hw_exit);
```

We can modprobe it, as shown:

```
            modprobe sig_mc_hw.ko
```

But, when we give a input command line parameter, we get a seg fault:

```
            modprobe sig_mc_hw.ko hwmode=0
```

dmesg shows that we have not reached the init() also. How do we debug that?

We upgraded from Fedora Linux version 2.6.34.10 to 2.6.34.15 by upgrading our Kernel header files. What other files are needed in order to do so?

We are running the module on PowerPC. Is cache alignment or any other method is needed when declaring a parameter?

```
        Thanks!
        Sarvani Chadalapaka
        HPC Systems Engineer
        Signalogic Inc
```

**Added on edit:**

Here is the Makefile

```
TARGET := sig_mc_hw
EXTRA_CFLAGS := -I/root/adsp2/usr/src/linux/include/linux 
KDIR = /root/adsp2/usr/src/linux
PWD  = $(shell pwd)
export ARCH=powerpc
export CROSS_COMPILE=ppc_e500v2-target-linux-gnu-
export LINUXROOT=/root/adsp2/usr/src/linux

obj-m += ${TARGET}.o 

all:

       make -C $(KDIR) ARCH=powerpc CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) M=${PWD} EXTRA_CFLAGS="$(EXTRA_CFLAGS)" modules
```

`uname -a` command shows the following: 2.6.34.15-WR4.3.0.0_standard #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 20 14:47:40 CST 2015 ppc GNU/Linux

modprobe commands show:

```
     ~# modprobe -v sig_mc_hw.ko 
     ~#
     ~# modprobe -v sig_mc_hw.ko hwmode=0
        Segmentation fault
```

Comment: What's `uname -a` and the `make` command used (and/or `Makefile` used)?  Does `modprobe -v ...` show anything?

Comment: Thanks for the added info.  What does `modprobe -v sig_mc_hw` show?  What does `modprobe -v sig_mc_hw hwmode=0` show?

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but kernel module programming is very detailed.  Is the `CROSS_COMPILE` really necessary?  I.e., you are building a kernel module to run on a different kernel/system?  Also, are you sure the includes in `EXTRA_CFLAGS` have only header files, etc., that belong in the kernel?

Comment: Rick, thank you for your suggestion. Please find the edits in my post. `CROSS_COMPILE` is necessary since I am building the driver on one server and loading it on ATCA board that does not have any build tools. I need to have `-I/usr/include` in `EXTRA_CFLAGS` as that's where kernel.h and module.h are located. I temporarily renamed all other include files on that location.

Comment: Have you built the kernel running on the ATCA board via cross-compile on your development server?  The reason I ask is that the directories in your `Makefile` are unusual.

Comment: Yes Rick, we have the .ko running on the ATCA while we are building the .ko on a build server. The Kernel Directory for "cross build" is /root/adsp2/usr/src/linux

Comment: Seems like compiler optimized away not used variable. Try to supply it to printk at exit.

Comment: Andy, thanks for your response. We are not even getting into the init function,. However, I tried supplying a printk at exit as you suggested and still see the seg fault when I give a command line parameter while loading.

Comment: Rick, we have upgraded the minor version of kernel from 2.6.34 .10 to 2.6.34 .15 and we are cross compiling. What other files besides the header files do we need in order to build a .ko?

Comment: @sarvanichadalapaka it is not enough to update kernel-header, you  need also kernel-devel to be update (to the same version of kernel-headers you are building against).

Comment: I am wondering if you are building the module for the exact correct kernel.  Perhaps the instructions/guidance at [Building modules for a precompiled kernel](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x380.html) will help.

Comment: Just notice the "WR" part of your kernel spec.  Doesn't Wind River's VxWorks come with an IDE (Workbench?) and Board Support Packages (BSP's) to help you create kernel modules and applications?